# how to call activity from inputmethodservice and pass data to Inputmethodsevice from activity

Tags: android

I have a soft keyboard as a inputmethodservice calling an activity. A button is pressed and a scanner is activated. The scanner activity captures a set of data then returns the data to the inputmethodservice for filling in a text field on a browser.

How do I return the scan value of the activity back to the inputmethodservice and how to set to getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(data, 1)?
the following snnipet for call scannerActivity

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
                final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(
                        "com.example.android.softkeyboard",
                        "com.example.android.softkeyboard.ScannerActivity");
                intent.setComponent(cn);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't you use the startActivityForResult instead?

Comment: That will be no use, because the Activity is started from an InputMethodService

Answer (score 0):

`use this way`

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{    
 if(resultCode == 0)
 {    
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
   {    
    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("your string");    
    }    
}    
};
```

Comment: Hi Dhaval,thank you very much for reply to this question but my problem is not solved.Because First i went scanner Activity it is successfully done.After that i pass data from scanner activity to softkeyboard(its not an activity). I need how to achieve this..... plz guide me...... onActivityResult is not used for me.